# Want to connect my Android device (mobile / tablet) to Printer for application print purpose

Tags: android, printing, connection

I want to bring a functionality to my `Android app`, that users can connect from `mobile device (mobile or tablet)` via `USB / Wi-Fi / Bluetooth` and can take out the prints.

I search over the Internet but not finding any proper solution which is achieving results.

Looking for your help / guide further to decide our Android Application scope.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: http://www.androidsim.net/2011/12/how-to-43-setup-google-cloud-print-for.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Star Micronics has an SDK for Android printing via Bluetooth, WiFi, and USB. You can download it here: http://www.starmicronics.com/support/SDKDocumentation.aspx.

This SDK has a really nice sample app that lets you test and customize a lot of printer functions to see them in action. Each function is documented in the source code. The commands and their parameters are also available in the app itself as a quick on screen reference which is convenient. On top of all that, it's well documented.

Basically, you can send plain text to the printer along with commands. The API handles converting the data into what the printer can understand.

Comment: Wifi functionality is not avilable in this demo and i need to connect the printer with tablet in android with wifi connection. so please helo me out.